# "Segmentation Fault" in matplotlib running example Librosa script

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, matplotlib, librosa

After many issues I've installed Librosa (https://github.com/librosa/librosa) on Linux Mint 18 Mate x64. When I want to run example script, e.g.: http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.tempogram.html#librosa.feature.tempogram, it crashes with "Segmentation Fault" error:

```
$ python librosa-feature-tempogram-1.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py:140: Warning: g_main_context_push_thread_default: assertion 'acquired_context' failed
  qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication([str(" ")])
Segmentation fault
```

I've tried to debug it line-by-line and there is result:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import librosa

>>> # Visualize an STFT power spectrum
... 
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.util.example_audio_file())

>>> plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py:140: Warning: g_main_context_push_thread_default: assertion 'acquired_context' failed
  qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication([str(" ")])
Segmentation fault
```

Probably there is some issue with matplotlib library and Qt (5.7.0). Moreover, I remember I had many issues when installing Librosa, including matplotlib, so it could be some installation issue. However, I don't know how to solve it. I hope somebody will have helpful clues for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've solved this issue by installing these packages: `sudo apt-get install tk-dev libpng-dev libffi-dev dvipng texlive-latex-base` and reinstalling *matplotlib* using *pip*. I have also changed background in *matplotlib* on *TkAgg*. There is a beginning of a code with import statements:

```
import librosa
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I just needed the `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` line